# Handling manual inputs in ssh script

Tags: server, bash, scripts, ssh

I am accessing a remote machine using ssh and have written a simple bash script on my host pc to copy files from the remote computer to the host.

which is simply:  `scp remote@ip:/path/to/file/ destination`

But I get this promt everytime to input the password for the remote machine and am therefore not able to run this script while I am away from the computer.

Is there any way around this difficulty. for example, I do not have to type the password but it can access it from some file available in host directory automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: See this thread on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp

Comment: Thanks! that worked